# How can I include common behavior in several Apache Camel routes?

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I am using Camel 2.19.2 in a Spring Boot 1.5.8 application.  If I want, for example, to have several of my routes to be "status aware", how might I achieve this?  What I mean by "status aware" is that the route will start, notify a component that the workflow has begun, then it will conduct route-specific logic, and when that is complete, it will notify a component that the workflow has completed.  I want this to happen automatically, if possible, and without having to call the specific logic in each of the route builders that I want to use this capability.

Here is a code example like what I mean:

```
public class FooRouteBuilder extends StatusAwareRouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        // Here I want to have this route know how to notify something
        // that this processing has begun, but I do not want to have
        // to explicitly call a processor to make it happen, but it
        // should know what to do by virtue of extending a custom
        // route builder, if appropriate, or by some other/better
        // mechanism

        // Now conduct any route-specific logic
        from("vm:myAction")
            .process("myProcessor");

        // Now handle the status notification that this is finished...
        // Here I want to have this route know how to notify something
        // that this processing has finished
    }
}
```

Conceptually, this is almost like AOP, so I would like to be able to define this behavior in one place and include it in some number of routes that need to use this behavior.  Is there a way that I can accomplish this?  I saw that there is adviceWith for testing, but I need this for regular operation.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that RoutePolicy and RoutePolicyFactory can be the answer, i.e. you can have a callback invoked when the route or exchnage start/stop.

For more info see http://camel.apache.org/routepolicy.html

Comment: I need it to happen every time a route is invoked (when a message is passed to it), and not only on route start/stop.

Comment: so have a look at onExchangeBegin / onExchangeDone

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [Camel interceptors](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/intercept.adoc) can help you. These are typically small **generic routes that are applied to all or most of your routes**.

For example to do a security check in every route. With an interceptor you write it once and it is applied to all routes, even new ones that are added.

There are three flavours.

- `intercept` intercepts each and every processing step while routing
  an Exchange in the route.
- `interceptFrom` intercepts every incoming
  Exchange in the route (start of processing)
- `interceptSendToEndpoint` intercepts when an
  Exchange is about to be sent to an endpoint.

The interceptors can be configured to "fire" only for specific endpoint types or by [Camel predicate](http://camel.apache.org/predicate.html) on other specific conditions.

There is also the [`onCompletion` feature](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/user-manual/en/oncompletion.adoc) to **do a similar thing at route completion**. Either on successful completion on failure completion or both of them (default).

Comment: This solution intrigues me, but I would only want the intercept to happen for designated routes, and only upon start of a route and then again at the completion of the route (regardless of normal completion or exception).  I could not discern if this was possible from that documentation.

Comment: I have extended my answer a bit. Start of a route: `interceptFrom`; route completion: `onCompletion`. Only certain routes: use a Predicate to define the routes the interceptor is applied to.